# Application crashes while deploying in heroku

Tags: java, maven, heroku

I have developed a java based webapp. Im trying to push it to heroku so as to test my webapp. Following is my pom.xml file content

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebMobileGroupChatServer</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebMobileGroupChatServer</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            <appName>boiling-ocean-21071</appName>
       <processTypes>
     <web>java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* Main</web>
     </processTypes>
        </configuration>

      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
      </plugin>
      <!-- <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
       -->
       <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals><goal>copy-dependencies</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>appassembler-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <assembleDirectory>target</assembleDirectory>
                <programs>
                    <program>
                        <mainClass>launch.Main</mainClass>
                        <name>webapp</name>
                    </program>
                </programs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>assemble</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
      <dependencies>
      <dependency>
      <groupId>org.json</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20140107</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-collections -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
    <version>r03</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Following is my  Pocfile content

```
web: sh target/bin/webapp
```

The problem is that when im running this code, App crashes.

It throws the following error message

```
at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=2f38b729-4aa9-4895-a830-9d847b3fe763 fwd="122.165.238.99" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: How are you deploying? Git or mvn?

Comment: im deploying it through git

Comment: Then you can remove the heroku-maven-plugin stuff. What is generating the `target/bin/webapp` file?

Comment: SocketServer is the java file that generates it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. It probably needs to be configured with the correct port, which is determined by the `$PORT` env var on Heroku.

Comment: If you just need to run a war file, I recommend looking at a sample app like this https://github.com/kissaten/webapp-runner-minimal

Comment: how can i run using war file?

Comment: it says `Error: Unable to access jarfile webapp-runner.jar`